# Do postfix operators return lvalue when applied on ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++11, postfix-operator

Isn't the foll code given in C++ Primer incorrect ?

```
ostream_iterator<int> out_iter(cout, " ");
for (auto e : vec)
    *out_iter++ = e;  // the assignment writes this element to cout
cout << endl;
```

The postfix operator returns the old value, not a reference then how can it be made to act as an lvalue ?

Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: `out_iter++` is not an lvalue. It's an iterator rvalue. `*out_iter++` is an lvalue.

Comment: You are misreading the operator precedence. `*out_iter++` means `*(out_iter++)`, not `(*out_ptr)++`.

Comment: @n.m. Are you sure? As far as I can see, `out_iter++` is lvalue itself as well.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan you are right, ++ here returns a reference so it is an lvalue, but only because it's an ostream iterator. Other iterators don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith

> ostream_iterator& operator++();
>
> ostream_iterator& operator++( int );

but operator* and operators ++ of `ostream_iterator` do nothing, they only return reference to `*this`, so you can write this

```
for (auto e : vec)
    out_iter = e;  // the assignment writes this element to cout
```

and the output will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The code is OK as:

```
*out_iter++ = e;
```

is equal to:

```
*(out_iter++) = e;
```

so postfix increment happens first and then dereference is performed.

From [`operator++`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith):

```
ostream_iterator& operator++();
ostream_iterator& operator++( int );
```

> Does nothing. **They make it possible for the expressions *iter++=value and
>   *++iter=value to be used to output (insert) a value into the underlying stream.**
>
> Return value
>
> *this

From [`operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator*):

```
ostream_iterator& operator*();
```

> It returns the iterator itself, which makes it possible to use code
>   such as *iter = value to output (insert) the value into the underlying
>   stream.
>
> Return value
>
> *this

Basically, it means that `*(out_iter++)` returns the reference to the iterator itself so one can write to the stream in the form of `*(out_iter++) = value`.